# Get argument from route function in my own decorator in flask

Tags: flask, arguments, decorator

In the flask, between the route function and the view function, how can I obtain the argument so that I can define a new decorator? Here I show an example.

```
@app.route('/Page/<int:Num>')
@HowToGetNum(Num)  # here I do not know how to get Num
def Page(Num):
    ....
```

The parameter Num will be passed into Page. But before that, I want to define a new decorator "HowToGetNum". However, I found there is no way to pass Num into it. Any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

In python decorator operate on the function before they are used.

What's actually going on is the Page function is being redefined.

Page = HowToGetNum(Page)

What you can do is define HowToGetNum as:

```
def HowToGetNum(func):
  def GetsNum(Num):
    # do something with Num
    func(Num)
  return GetsNum
```

So the new function has your functionality then runs the original Page